# Ubuntu Software Package in DVD

Tags: apt, updates

I have a brand new installation of Vivid Vervet in an offline PC.

What I want to do is, to download and burn a huge pack of software and updates in my other machine, to install it in the offline one.

Is there such thing to download officially, like in the old days?

Comment: What "in the old days" are you referring to?

Comment: Before Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure. You can do that...

Just go to [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.com) and download your huge load of software as .deb packages, put them on your other machine and install each on with

```
sudo dpkg -i somepackage.deb
```

**;D**